# "CLSRSC-1003: Failed to start resource OC4J" while executing root.sh during installation of Oracle Grid 12C R1

Tags: oracle, grid, oc4j

I am a new member on *Oracle Grid*. Now I am raising this question regarding the installation of Oracle Grid 12.1.0.2.

During the installation step, it appears that i need to run root.sh and then finish the installation.
[the installation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXGfN.png)

While when i executing the root.sh on my first node "rac1", i faced problem:

> 2016/12/13 02:58:02 CLSRSC-1003: Failed to start resource OC4J
>   2016/12/13 02:58:02 CLSRSC-287: FirstNode configuration failed

I am attaching the full trace for your reference.

===============start=================

```
[root@rac1 12.1.0]# ./root.sh 
Performing root user operation.

The following environment variables are set as:
    ORACLE_OWNER= grid
    ORACLE_HOME=  /grid/app/grid/12.1.0

Enter the full pathname of the local bin directory: [/usr/local/bin]: 
   Copying dbhome to /usr/local/bin ...
   Copying oraenv to /usr/local/bin ...
   Copying coraenv to /usr/local/bin ...


Creating /etc/oratab file...
Entries will be added to the /etc/oratab file as needed by
Database Configuration Assistant when a database is created
Finished running generic part of root script.
Now product-specific root actions will be performed.
Using configuration parameter file: /grid/app/grid/12.1.0/crs/install/crsconfig_params
2016/12/13 02:46:58 CLSRSC-4001: Installing Oracle Trace File Analyzer (TFA) Collector.

2016/12/13 02:47:22 CLSRSC-4002: Successfully installed Oracle Trace File Analyzer (TFA) 

Collector.

2016/12/13 02:47:23 CLSRSC-363: User ignored prerequisites during installation

OLR initialization - successful
  root wallet
  root wallet cert
  root cert export
  peer wallet
  profile reader wallet
  pa wallet
  peer wallet keys
  pa wallet keys
  peer cert request
  pa cert request
  peer cert
  pa cert
  peer root cert TP
  profile reader root cert TP
  pa root cert TP
  peer pa cert TP
  pa peer cert TP
  profile reader pa cert TP
  profile reader peer cert TP
  peer user cert
  pa user cert
2016/12/13 02:48:00 CLSRSC-330: Adding Clusterware entries to file 'oracle-ohasd.service'

CRS-4133: Oracle High Availability Services has been stopped.
CRS-4123: Oracle High Availability Services has been started.
CRS-4133: Oracle High Availability Services has been stopped.
CRS-4123: Oracle High Availability Services has been started.
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.cssdmonitor' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.cssdmonitor' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.diskmon' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.diskmon' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1' succeeded

ASM created and started successfully.

Disk Group DATA created successfully.

CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.crf' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.storage' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.storage' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.crf' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-4256: Updating the profile
Successful addition of voting disk 6932ae2c00044f73bfeec2045787fe33.
Successfully replaced voting disk group with +DATA.
CRS-4256: Updating the profile
CRS-4266: Voting file(s) successfully replaced

[Insert picture here because special format][2]

Located 1 voting disk(s).
CRS-2791: Starting shutdown of Oracle High Availability Services-managed resources on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.crf' on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.ctssd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.storage' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.storage' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.asm' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.crf' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.ctssd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.asm' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.cluster_interconnect.haip' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.cluster_interconnect.haip' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2673: Attempting to stop 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2677: Stop of 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2793: Shutdown of Oracle High Availability Services-managed resources on 'rac1' has 

completed
CRS-4133: Oracle High Availability Services has been stopped.
CRS-4123: Starting Oracle High Availability Services-managed resources
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.evmd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.mdnsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.gpnpd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.gipcd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.cssdmonitor' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.cssdmonitor' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.diskmon' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.diskmon' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.cssd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.cluster_interconnect.haip' on 'rac1'
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.ctssd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.ctssd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.cluster_interconnect.haip' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.asm' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.asm' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.storage' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.storage' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.crf' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.crf' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.crsd' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-6023: Starting Oracle Cluster Ready Services-managed resources
CRS-6017: Processing resource auto-start for servers: rac1
CRS-6016: Resource auto-start has completed for server rac1
CRS-6024: Completed start of Oracle Cluster Ready Services-managed resources
CRS-4123: Oracle High Availability Services has been started.
2016/12/13 02:52:23 CLSRSC-343: Successfully started Oracle Clusterware stack

CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.ASMNET1LSNR_ASM.lsnr' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.ASMNET1LSNR_ASM.lsnr' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.asm' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.asm' on 'rac1' succeeded
CRS-2672: Attempting to start 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'rac1'
CRS-2676: Start of 'ora.DATA.dg' on 'rac1' succeeded
2016/12/13 02:58:02 CLSRSC-1003: Failed to start resource OC4J

2016/12/13 02:58:02 CLSRSC-287: FirstNode configuration failed

Died at /grid/app/grid/12.1.0/crs/install/crsinstall.pm line 2398.
The command '/grid/app/grid/12.1.0/perl/bin/perl -I/grid/app/grid/12.1.0/perl/lib -

I/grid/app/grid/12.1.0/crs/install /grid/app/grid/12.1.0/crs/install/rootcrs.pl ' execution 

failed
```

=====================end========================

Could you help me on it please?

1). How to narrow down this issue? Like from which path/log could i get more information?

2). How could i overcome this error please?

**Information:**

- Oracle Grid 12.1.0.2
- CentOS 7.2

Thank you very much!

Thanks
Andrew Chen

Comment: Was there previous RAC installed on this machine and you have deleted and tried to reinstall Oracle 12c GI? Also check OC4J logs located under `$GRID_HOME/oc4j/j2ee/home/log` directory.

Comment: @atokpas I have same issue yes I have tried to install RAC 12c and deleted it because of failed install and now with new install I got same error how to solve this error please ?

Answer (score 0):

> How to narrow down this issue?
>
> Like from which path/log could i get more information?

Please investigate the cluster alert logs located under
`$ORACLE_BASE/diag/crs/<hostname>/crs/trace/` and OC4J log under `$GRID_HOME/oc4j/j2ee/home/log` directories.

> How could i overcome this error please?

There might incorrect entries in `/etc/hosts` file.

Sample `/etc/hosts` file-

```
#::1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

#eth Public
192.0.2.100       racnode1.example.com       racnode1
192.0.2.101       racnode2.example.com       racnode2

#eth1 Private ...
```

Re run the `root.sh` script after correcting the entries in `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Hello , I have same issue I checked the log file and this is the error "Error starting ORMI server rac1 port 23,792: Address already in use"?